# Why does increasing a number by 15% and then decreasing it by 15% fail to produce the original number?

Tags: arithmetic, percentages

I start with number: $.425$ and I want to add $15\%$ to get a new number.  $.425 \times 1.15 = .489$  However, when I reduce $.489$ by $15\%$ I don't arrive back at $.425$. $.489 \times .85 = .416$. I need to reduce $.499$ by $15\%$ in order to to arrive at $.425$.  I would love your help to get my head around something this simple!

Comment: $15$% of $0.489$ is more than $15$% of $0.425$, so when you subtract $15$% of $0.489$, you’re subtracting more than you added in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

If you consider what you're doing algebraically, when you increase a number $x$ by a portion of $k$, you are performing the operation
$$x+kx$$
where we take the original amount, then add it to $kx$, the portion extra we want. This could be more easily expressed as multiplying $x(1+k)=x+kx$, by the distributive property. Similarly, subtracting a portion of $k$ is the operator $x-kx =x(1-k)$. So, if we increase $x$ by a factor of $k$, we get $x(1+k)$, and then if we decrease it by that same factor, we get $x(1+k)(1-k)$, which can be expanded as:
$$x(1-k^2)$$
which is not equal to $x$ - and is in fact, always less than the amount we started with.

So, try to think not "adding 15%" and "subtracting 15%" but "multiply by 115%" and "multiplying by 85%" - where there is less temptation to think you're *actually* adding or subtracting anything. Namely, to undo this sort of thing, we need the reciprocal (e.g. $\frac{1}{1.15}$), which is not equal to $2-k$, as would be necessary for adding and subtracting a portion to cancel out.

Comment: Meelo, that makes sense although I couldn't repeat it. Jack offered 100x50% is 150, but 150 / 50% is 75. Simple for me lol. So here's my next question, which I'm thinking you're trying to give me above. I start with .425 (Rate) and I surcharge it 15%, but my modified Rate now displays as .499 so system is creating that somehow.  What math do I manually perform to arrive at .499 when surcharging .425 by 15%?

Comment: Well, getting $.499$ as an answer is a bit odd - it's probably just a machine being weird or trying to make a price look lower or something - $.5$ seems more reasonable as the "actual" answer - notice that if you multiply $.5$ by $.85$ (i.e. decrease it by 15%), you get $.425$ - that is, that is the number which is gotten by "undoing" the operation "subtract 15%". This operation is actually "add 17.6%" not "add 15%" (equivalently, it is "divide by 85%" - which is the same as multiplying by the reciprocal 1/.85, which is about 117.6%)

Comment: Okay so I'm not completely outside my mind, thinking this system is not returning correct Rate. I'll check with my developers tomorrow, so they can check Code.  I thought maybe it was me.  Thanks so much Meelo!!!